# NotificationCenter Selector method is not calling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to send first viewcontroller textfield data into second viewcontroller label.

In first controller, Inside send action button adding notification post method

```
 @IBAction func sendtBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let secVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secVc, animated: true)

     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name( "notificationName"), object: nil, userInfo: ["text": firstTextField.text])
   }
```

And second  viewcontroller addobserver method inside view didload

```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showMsg(_:)), name: Notification.Name( "notificationName"), object: nil)
```

Selector function :

```
func showMsg(_ notification: Notification){
    print("helloooo")
    var vcData = notification.userInfo?["text"]
    firstLabel.text = vcData as! String
}
```

When keeping break points for add observer it observers but it does not calling showMsg function.
Please help me in this code.

Comment: Check using breakpoints if the notification is being posted. Also, why have your used `Notification.Name` in `post` and `NSNotification.Name` in `observer`? Also you can change the type of `notification` in `showMsg` to `Notification` instead of `NSNotification`.

Comment: replace `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName")` with `NSNotification.Name( "notificationName")`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri And pratik prajapati I have replaced NSNotification.Name( "notificationName") and Notification still showMsg() is not calling

Comment: @Swift edit the question with the latest code and what happened to checking if the notification is being posted with breakpoint?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri i have edited my question and when i use breakpoint both post and observer are calling but  showMsg is not calling

Comment: Your second piece of code still says `NSNotification.Name( "notificationName")` while you are posting Notification using `Notification.Name( "notificationName")`. I don't know if this will affect the notification since `Notification` is a wrapper over `NSNotification` but it's already bad practise to be using both. If it still doesn't work. That means your selector is not within the scope of the notification. Show the rest of your code.

Comment: May be you post the notification before adding the observer..@Swift

Comment: @RakeshaShastri sorry i have edited my code, is there anything to change in my code, still showMsg() not calling

Comment: _Show the rest of your code. _ Show the rest of your code in context with your current code.

Comment: @Swift first add the observer then post the notification

Comment: @SaurabhJain in first viewcontroller i have textfield so i have added post in firstviewcontroller and in second viewcontroller i have added observer, what should i change in this

Comment: This is not the right way use to NotificationCenter...you should use another approach..like pass data via segue or something else @Swift

Comment: @Swift see the below answer..

Comment: For testing the notification--> first go to the secondViewController after that come back to firstViewController then call the sendtBtn method...then your notification work perfectly @Swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **do** have the reference to the second view controller. **There is no reason at all to use `Notification`**. Don't use notifications if there is only one receiver and the objects are related.

The code doesn't work because the view is not loaded yet when the notification is sent.

Forget the notification. Instead create a property in the second view controller, assign the value in `sendtBtn` and show the message in `viewDidLoad`

```
@IBAction func sendtBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let secVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    secVc.message = firstTextField.text
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secVc, animated: true)

}
```

Second view controller

```
var message = ""

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstLabel.text = message
}
```